# jquery slideToggle - Call before slide

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Can anyone suggest how to make a call within slideToggle before it opens/closes?
Here is my situation:

```
$('.accordion .d_row .c_row').live('click', function() {

    $(this).nextAll('div.details').slideToggle(function() {

        if($(this).is(":hidden")){
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }

    });
});
```

If i call anything where the //do something comment resides this getss fired whilst the element slides open. Is there a way to call, for example, a function first then perform the silde?

Cheers

Comment: Does it work if you set `slideToggle()`'s first argument to `500`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just run your code before calling `slideToggle`.